# Loading contacts from phonebook causing the app to stop

Tags: android

I am trying to fetch all the contacts from phonebook and show them in a ListView. The problem is contacts have been fetched & showed successfully in ListView but just after few seconds the app is goint to be crashed, fetching contact list & fitting items in ListView everything is sucessfull but app is crashed after some time.
Here is MainActivity.java-

```
   public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
   // ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] values;
Context mContext;
String Name;
int j=0,c=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext())
        {
        Name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
       c=c+1;
        }
        phones.close();
        values = new String[c];
       fun();
       MyArrayAdapter  adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(this, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    private void fun() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Cursor phones1 = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
         while (phones1.moveToNext())
            {
        Name=phones1.getString(phones1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String Number=phones1.getString(phones1.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        values[j]=Name;
        j=j+1;
            }
         phones1.close();
    }
}
```

and MyArrayAdapter.java is -

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
Context context;
String[] values;

public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_main, values);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;

    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
        TextView txtv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.member_name);
        TextView txtv1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.status);
        ImageView imgv = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
        Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ok);
        for(int pos = 0; pos<values.length;pos++)
        {
            txtv.setText(values[position]);
            imgv.setImageBitmap(icon);

        }
                return v;
    }

}
```

Please help!

Comment: What is the error you get on the logcat?

Comment: Provide detailed error with codes so.people.can help you. So What Error are you getting?

Comment: sorry.... but i am unable to see logcat...

Answer (score 1):

You should load contact and pass the result to your Adapter in Background Service e.g. AsyncTask,  IntentService as running long operations on UI Thread will always crash your Application.

Comment: And do lazy loading for view.

Comment: do you consider querying `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI` as a "running long operation" ?

Comment: It is not about just the query but what the query might return. A query that returns just the name is different from.the one that returns name, number, email and image.